# cuando guardo informacion en la tabla solo aparece en la base de datos y en netbeans aparece como una nueva columna

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans, phpmyadmin

Frame habitación

```
import Datos.vhabitacion;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import primero_lo.fHabitacion;


public class Habitaciones extends javax.swing.JFrame {

  public Habitaciones() {
      initComponents();
      Mostrar("");
      inhabilitar();


  }
 private String accion = "Guardar";

void ocultar_columnas(){
   tablalistado.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setMaxWidth(0);
   tablalistado.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setMinWidth(0);
   tablalistado.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setPreferredWidth(0);


 }

void inhabilitar() {
   txtidhabitacion.setVisible(false);
   cboPiso.setEnabled(false);
   txtNumero.setEnabled(false);
   txtDescripcion.setEnabled(false);
   txtcaracteristicas.setEnabled(false);
   txtPrecio_diario.setEnabled(false);
   cboEstado.setEnabled(false);
   cboTipo_Habitacion.setEnabled(false);

   btnGuardar.setEnabled(false);
   btnCancelar.setEnabled(false);
   btnEliminar.setEnabled(false);
   txtidhabitacion.setText("");
   txtPrecio_diario.setText("");
   txtcaracteristicas.setText("");
   txtDescripcion.setText("");


}

void habilitar() {
   txtidhabitacion.setVisible(false);
   cboPiso.setEnabled(true);
   txtNumero.setEnabled(true);
   txtDescripcion.setEnabled(true);
   txtcaracteristicas.setEnabled(true);
   txtPrecio_diario.setEnabled(true);
   cboEstado.setEnabled(true);
   cboTipo_Habitacion.setEnabled(true);

   btnGuardar.setEnabled(true);
   btnCancelar.setEnabled(true);
   btnEliminar.setEnabled(true);
   txtidhabitacion.setText("");
   txtPrecio_diario.setText("");
   txtcaracteristicas.setText("");
   txtDescripcion.setText("");

}

void Mostrar(String buscar) {
    try {
        DefaultTableModel modelo;
        fHabitacion func=new fHabitacion();
        modelo =func.Mostrar(buscar);

        tablalistado.setModel(modelo);
        ocultar_columnas();
        lblTotalregistros.setText("Total Registros" + Integer.toString(func.totalRegistros));

    } catch (Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(rootPane, e);

    }



}



*//boton nuevo* 
  habilitar();
  btnGuardar.setText("Guardar");
  accion="Guardar";


 *//boton guardar*

 btnGuardar if(txtNumero.getText().length() == 0){
     JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(rootPane, "Debes ingresar un Numero de Habitacion");
     txtNumero.requestFocus();
     return;
 }
if (txtDescripcion.getText().length() == 0){
    JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(rootPane, "Debes ingresar una Descripcion para la Habitacion Habitacion");
    txtDescripcion.requestFocus();
    return;
}



 if(txtPrecio_diario.getText().length() == 0){
     JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(rootPane, "Debes ingresar un Precio DIaria para la Habitacion Habitacion");
     txtDescripcion.requestFocus();
     return;
 }
 if(txtcaracteristicas.getText().length()== 0){
 JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(rootPane, "Debes ingresar una caracteristica para la Habitacion Habitacion");
 txtcaracteristicas.requestFocus();
 return;
 }
 vhabitacion dts = new vhabitacion();
 fHabitacion func = new fHabitacion();

 dts.setNumero(txtNumero.getText());

 int seleccionado = cboPiso.getSelectedIndex();
 dts.setPiso((String)cboPiso.getItemAt(seleccionado));

 dts.setDescripcion(txtDescripcion.getText());
 dts.setCaracteristica(txtcaracteristicas.getText());

 dts.setPrecio_Diario(Double.parseDouble(txtPrecio_diario.getText()));

 seleccionado = cboEstado.getSelectedIndex();
 dts.setEstado((String) cboEstado.getItemAt(seleccionado));

 seleccionado = cboTipo_Habitacion.getSelectedIndex();
 dts.setTipo_habitacion((String) cboTipo_Habitacion.getItemAt(seleccionado));


 if(accion.equals("Guardar")){
     if(func.insertar(dts)){
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, "La habitacion fue registrada correctamente");
         Mostrar("");
         inhabilitar();
     }
 }
 else if(accion.equals("Editar")){
     dts.setIdHabitacion(Integer.parseInt(txtidhabitacion.getText()));

     if(func.Editar(dts)){
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, "La Habitacion fue editada correctamente");
         Mostrar("");
         inhabilitar();
     }
 }
}


*//boton eliminar*
if(!txtidhabitacion.getText().equals("")){
    int confirmacion = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(rootPane, "Estas seguro de eliminar la Habitacion?","confirmar",2);

    if(confirmacion==0){
        fHabitacion func = new fHabitacion();
        vhabitacion dts = new vhabitacion();

        dts.setIdHabitacion(Integer.parseInt(txtidhabitacion.getText()));
        func.Eliminar(dts);
        Mostrar("");
        inhabilitar();
    }
}
```

**Vhabitacion**

```
public class vhabitacion {
private int idHabitacion;
private String Numero;
private String Piso;
private String Descripcion;
private String Caracteristica;
private Double Precio_Diario;
private String Estado;
private String Tipo_habitacion;

public vhabitacion(int idHabitacion, String Numero, String Piso, String Descripcion, String Caracteristica, Double Precio_Diario, String Estado, String Tipo_habitacion) {
    this.idHabitacion = idHabitacion;
    this.Numero = Numero;
    this.Piso = Piso;
    this.Descripcion = Descripcion;
    this.Caracteristica = Caracteristica;
    this.Precio_Diario = Precio_Diario;
    this.Estado = Estado;
    this.Tipo_habitacion = Tipo_habitacion;
}

public vhabitacion() {
}

public int getIdHabitacion() {
    return idHabitacion;
}

public void setIdHabitacion(int idHabitacion) {
    this.idHabitacion = idHabitacion;
}

public String getNumero() {
    return Numero;
}

public void setNumero(String Numero) {
    this.Numero = Numero;
}

public String getPiso() {
    return Piso;
}

public void setPiso(String Piso) {
    this.Piso = Piso;
}

public String getDescripcion() {
    return Descripcion;
}

public void setDescripcion(String Descripcion) {
    this.Descripcion = Descripcion;
}

public String getCaracteristica() {
    return Caracteristica;
}

public void setCaracteristica(String Caracteristica) {
    this.Caracteristica = Caracteristica;
}

public Double getPrecio_Diario() {
    return Precio_Diario;
}

public void setPrecio_Diario(Double Precio_Diario) {
    this.Precio_Diario = Precio_Diario;
}

public String getEstado() {
    return Estado;
}

public void setEstado(String Estado) {
    this.Estado = Estado;
}

public String getTipo_habitacion() {
    return Tipo_habitacion;
}

public void setTipo_habitacion(String Tipo_habitacion) {
    this.Tipo_habitacion = Tipo_habitacion;
}

}
```

**fhabitacion**

```
import Datos.vhabitacion;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;

import java.sql.Statement;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

public class fHabitacion {
 private Ingreso mysql=new    Ingreso();
 private Connection cn=mysql.conectar();
 private String sSQL="";
 public Integer totalRegistros;

 public DefaultTableModel Mostrar(String buscar){
    DefaultTableModel modelo;

   String [] titulos =  {"ID","Numero","Piso","Descripción","Caracteristicas","Precio","Estado","Tipo  de habitacion"};
  String [] Registros = new String [8];
  totalRegistros=0;
  modelo = new DefaultTableModel(null,titulos);
  sSQL="select * from Habitacion where piso like '%"+buscar+ "%'order by idHabitacion";
   try {
       Statement st= cn.createStatement();
       ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery(sSQL);
       while(rs.next()){
          Registros[0]=rs.getString("idHabitacion");
          Registros[1]=rs.getString("Numero");
          Registros[2]=rs.getString("Piso");
          Registros[3]=rs.getString("Descripcion");
          Registros[4]=rs.getString("Caracteristica");
          Registros[5]=rs.getString("Precio_Diario");
          Registros[6]=rs.getString("Estado");
          Registros[7]=rs.getString("Tipo_habitacion");

          totalRegistros=totalRegistros+1;
          modelo.addColumn(Registros);

       }
       return modelo;
   } catch (Exception e) {
       JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, e);
       return null;
   }
   }


public boolean Insetar (vhabitacion dts){

 sSQL="Insertar into Habitacion (Numero,Piso,Descripciion,Caracteristicas,Precio_Diario,Tipo_habitacion)"+
           "values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
   try {
       PreparedStatement pst=cn.prepareStatement(sSQL);
       pst.setString(1, dts.getNumero());
       pst.setString(2, dts.getPiso());
       pst.setString(3, dts.getDescripcion());
       pst.setString(4, dts.getCaracteristica());
       pst.setDouble(5, dts.getPrecio_Diario());
       pst.setString(6, dts.getEstado());
       pst.setString(7, dts.getTipo_habitacion());

       int n=pst.executeUpdate();
       if(n!=0){
           return true;

       }
       else{
           return false;
       }


   } catch (Exception e) {
       JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, e);
       return false;
   }
   }


public boolean Editar (vhabitacion dts){
    sSQL="Update  Habitacion set Numero=?,Piso=?,Descripcion=?,Caracteristicas=?,Precio_Diario=?,Tipo_habitacion=?"+
           " where idHabitacion";

   try {
            PreparedStatement pst=cn.prepareStatement(sSQL);
       pst.setString(1, dts.getNumero());
       pst.setString(2, dts.getPiso());
       pst.setString(3, dts.getDescripcion());
       pst.setString(4, dts.getCaracteristica());
       pst.setDouble(5, dts.getPrecio_Diario());
       pst.setString(6, dts.getEstado());
       pst.setString(7, dts.getTipo_habitacion());
       pst.setInt(8, dts.getIdHabitacion());
       int n=pst.executeUpdate();
       if(n!=0){
           return true;

       }
       else{
           return false;
       }

   } catch (Exception e) {
       JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, e);
       return false;
   }
}
```

**conexión**

```
public class Ingreso {
public String db="base";
public String url="jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1/" +db;
public String user="root";
public String pass="";

public Ingreso() {
}

public Connection conectar(){
    Connection link=null;

    try {
        Class.forName("org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver");
        link=DriverManager.getConnection(this.url, this.user, this.pass);

    } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e) {
        JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, e);

    }

    return link;
}

}
```

[acá si figuran](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RlhOd.jpg)
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
sin embargo acá salen como nuevas columnas
[image: sin embargo acá salen como nuevas columnas]

Gracias por su ayuda!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

En vez de addColumn quizá deberías usar addRow.
addColumn se usa para agregar columnas, mientras addRow se usa para agregar filas.
[image: fhabitacion]

Comment: bienvenido se agradece tu apoyo en la comunidad, pero tu respuesta es muy escaza agrega por favor mas contenido por ejemplo explicación del por que y un ejemplo, de lo contrario tal vez empieces a recibir votos negativos

Comment: Gracias! Me sirvió de mucho